# how to access UI element values in layout.filename

Tags: android, xml, resources, preferences

I have made a custom class extending Preferences. I have used that custom class in a XML layout file and need to access the values there. 
part of my layout file:

```
<MyCustomClass
android:id="@+id/custom01"
android:title="ineedthistext" />
```

How can I retrieve "ineedthistext" as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via the class constructor:

```
public MyCustomClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    ...
    // Get an attribute
    X var = attrs.getX(...);
}
```